# Difference between different ways of starting node+express application?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm learning Node and Express and noticed that there are many ways of starting an application and wanted to know the difference between them [if any]. My application is called nodetest and these are the steps I followed first:

- Installed express and express-generator via npm.
- express nodetest
- cd nodetest && npm install

These are the 3 different ways I found one can start the node+express application:

1. DEBUG=nodetest ./bin/www
2. node ./bin/www
3. ./bin/www

How are they different ? When should I use which ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are setting the environment variable DEBUG to be equal to nodetest and running the executable ./bin/www, which will be interpreted by the node interpreter assuming it has `#!/usr/bin/env node` inside
2. You are explicitly calling the node interpreter to run the ./bin/www script
3. You are starting the ./bin/www and relying on your shell to know how to run the script (just like in case 1)

2 and 3 are equivalent. 1 is similar to 2 and 3 except that you are also setting the DEBUG environment variable.

Comment: As I learn this more, I understand how basic this question is :). Thank you.